# Android upper Copy/Paste toolbar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-theme, android-actionbaractivity

I need your assistance with the following issue in android dev.
For some reason when I extend ActioBarActivity the cut/copy/paste buttons are displayed correctly when I press the EditText component (see image 1).

[image]

Unfortunately, if I extend Activity, the toolbar is not displayed correctly. You can see on image 2, that the buttons are present but they are white and the user cannot see them. I have investigated but I'm not sure how to fix this.

[image]

If you need I can share the code but I think this can be easily reproduced.

Thanks in advance.

Paul

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a custom style and specify the background to the color you want, and in your theme xml resource file, between the "style" element, set the "android:actionBarStyle" to the custom style you just created, it'll change the action bar color for you.

Updated: I just used the default folder for my theme resource (Note: the file name is arbitrary), if you want to create a theme resource for v-11 (API level 11) and up, create a new theme resource file (again, file name is arbitrary) with a "-v11" suffixed to the name of the file.

[image: Folder structure]

This is the default theme resource file since it inherits properties and attributes from the `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar`, as you can notice, in this file, you MUST not use the "android" namespace. If you have another theme resource file, like in the picture above, Android Studio automatically created the `stylex.xml(v21)` which is for Android version 21 and up devices. You MUST add the "android" namespace to each and every attribute such as the `actionBarStyle` would become `android:actionBarStyle`, but you should now that, the ActionBar has been deprecated since version 21, API level 5.

Also, the `displayOptions` attribute tells Android about how the title area is shown. These are availabe values:

1. none
2. useLogo
3. showHome
4. homeAsUp
5. showTitle
6. showCustom
7. disableHome

Note: the `background` attribute ONLY accepts reference value, not hard-coded value.

[image: The default theme resource file]

Here is the result

[image: Final result]

Comment: Hey, sorry for the vague answer, see my revised version above.

Comment: This is a great answer and really helped me to get to know different things about Android's themes. The problem here is that basically I don't have an actionBar (I'm extending activity) and I need to apply style on the Cut/Copy/Paste toolbar that appears only when I long press the EditText box and select the text inside it. Do you have any idea regarding this?

Comment: "The problem here is that basically I don't have an actionBar (I'm extending activity)" You are very very wrong buddy. Every time you extend `Activity` (or the `ActionBarActivity` which is the support version of the platform's `Activity`), you will get the action bar, the cross bar with title is called the "Action Bar", if you don't want Action Bar, you have to use one of the "No Action Bar" theme such as "Theme.Holo.NoActionBar" theme.

Comment: "I need to apply style on the Cut/Copy/Paste toolbar that appears only when I long press the EditText box and select the text inside it." what you are trying to achieve here is called  the "Context Menu", it is like the action bar, but only appears within the context of you long-pressing an item and it triggers this "Context Menu", it temporarily takes over the action bar, but when you are done, it disappears. So if you dont want to style the action bar, your only choice is to create different images for those icons so they can be displayed correctly on a light background like your issue above

Comment: Were you ever able to figure out why the contexual actionbar was white on white?

Comment: it depends on the Android versions really

Answer (score 8):

Try using this in the definition of your app theme:

```
<item name="actionModeBackground">@color/actionBarBgColor</item>
```